# Why won't my justify-content: start work for Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to figure it out. Basically the idea is to have all the boxes clustered together, but somehow it ends up having a huuuuuuge margin between main and footer.
Please help.

CSS

Only css pertinent to the three boxed is added...

```css
body{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: start;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
     margin: 0;
 }
 header{
     background-color: white;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     width:100vw;
     height: 10vh;
     margin: 0;
 }
 main{
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 85vh;
     margin: 0;
 }
 footer{
     background-color: #666666;
     height: 4vh;
     width: 100vw;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="headercontentwrapper">
            <div id="logowrapper"></div>
            <div id="navwrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="contentheaderwrapper"></div>
            <div id="actualcontentwrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Setting MARGIN TO 0 FOR FOOTER DOES NOT HELP

Comment: well, your code seems to work.. ?

Comment: No, it does not since boxed should be scattered closer to the top of the page, but instead two of them do, but footer (THE THIRD ONE) has some sort of crazy offset off the two other boxes.

Comment: I just tested your code here and it seems fine to mee theres no margin all elements are placed correctly... EDIT: maybe it has to do with something else in your code ? because it's fine as is

Comment: There a small white line under the footer is that what you want to get rid of?

Comment: the small white line is because your elements are 10vh+85vh+4vh = 99vh instead of 100

Comment: The problem is when I set the footer's height to 5vh, it gets overflown to > 100% of the width.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex` instead of `height` for your flexbox childs.

```css
body{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: stretch;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       height: 100vh;
       width: 100vw;
       margin: 0;
   }
   header{
       background-color: white;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: center;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       width:100vw;
       flex: 0 0 10vh;
       margin: 0;
   }
   main{
       background-color: #f1f1f1;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: center;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       width: 100vw;
       flex: 1;
       margin: 0;
   }
   footer{
       background-color: #666666;
       flex: 0 0 4vh;
       width: 100vw;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="headercontentwrapper">
      <div id="logowrapper"></div>
      <div id="navwrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="contentwrapper">
      <div id="contentheaderwrapper"></div>
      <div id="actualcontentwrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I said in my comment, your code seems fine, maybe there's something else that is causing prblems?

ps: I made a snippet and corrected your tags

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: start;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 margin: 0;
}

header {
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 10vh;
 margin: 0;
}

main {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 85vh;
 margin: 0;
}

footer {
 background-color: #666666;
 height: 4vh;
 width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="headercontentwrapper">
            <div id="logowrapper"></div>
            <div id="navwrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="contentheaderwrapper"></div>
            <div id="actualcontentwrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think he meant he wanted to get rid of the white space under the footer?

Comment: "a huuuuuuge margin between main and footer"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `height: 85vh;` in your main, and everything is fine.
The problem is that your body is 100vh height, and the main takes 85vh. That's why there was a 'huuuuuge margin between main and footer' ;)

Hope it helped !